# Does Hellblade story happen in Senua head?

Tags: hellblade-senuas-sacrifice

After beating the game, I remain uncertain to what extent the events what the player witnesses is Senua imagination? Is entire story just one big dream? Were any of the gods/enemies real? Did Senua travel in the real world and see it altered or she was unconscious during the whole playthrough?